# WooCommerce Rest api create/update product variation problem

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to create/update a product variation through rest api and i have a problem.

My product attributes are filled correctly, with options on colour and on size. For example i have these on a product:

> “attributes”: [ { “id”: 1, “name”: “χρώμα”, “position”: 0, “visible”:
>   true, “variation”: true, “options”: [ “ΜΠΛΕ” ] }, { “id”: 2, “name”:
>   “μέγεθος”, “position”: 1, “visible”: true, “variation”: true,
>   “options”: [ “52”, “56”, “58”, “60”, “62”, “64”, “66” ] } ],

But when i am trying to fill the attributes on the variation, it returns [].
Example of posting:

> { “stock_quantity”: 2, “regular_price”: “22”, “sale_price”: “”,
>   “status”: “publish”, “purchasable”: true, “manage_stock”: true,
>   **“attributes”: [ { “id”: 1, “option”: “ΜΠΛΕ” }, { “id”: 2, “option”:
>   “60” } ]**, “meta_data”: [ { “key”: “Barcode”, “value”: “5207064064442”
>   } ] }

and it returns:

> { “id”: 6225, “date_created”: “2020-04-15T11:19:12”,
>   “date_created_gmt”: “2020-04-15T11:19:12”, “date_modified”:
>   “2020-04-22T17:11:32”, “date_modified_gmt”: “2020-04-22T17:11:32”,
>   “description”: “”, “sku”: “007887”, “price”: “22”, “regular_price”:
>   “22”, “sale_price”: “”, “date_on_sale_from”: null,
>   “date_on_sale_from_gmt”: null, “date_on_sale_to”: null,
>   “date_on_sale_to_gmt”: null, “on_sale”: false, “status”: “publish”,
>   “purchasable”: true, “virtual”: false, “downloadable”: false,
>   “downloads”: [], “download_limit”: -1, “download_expiry”: -1,
>   “tax_status”: “taxable”, “tax_class”: “”, “manage_stock”: true,
>   “stock_quantity”: 2, “stock_status”: “instock”, “backorders”: “no”,
>   “backorders_allowed”: false, “backordered”: false, “weight”: “”,
>   “dimensions”: { “length”: “”, “width”: “”, “height”: “” },
>   “shipping_class”: “”, “shipping_class_id”: 0, “image”: { “id”: 6192,
>   “date_created”: “2020-04-15T11:17:59”, “date_created_gmt”:
>   “2020-04-15T11:17:59”, “date_modified”: “2020-04-15T11:17:59”,
>   “date_modified_gmt”: “2020-04-15T11:17:59”, }, **“attributes”: []**,
>   “menu_order”: 0, “meta_data”: [ { “id”: 96831, “key”: “Barcode”,
>   “value”: “5207064064442” } ] }

All the data that i am sending, as stock_quantity, regular_price, meta_data etc are filled corectly. All except **attributes**.

Any solution?!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A little late for the response but you should try to use `woocommerce` rest api `v2` instead of `v3` for example `{siteUrl}/wp-json/wc/v2/products/{product_id}/variations` instead of `{siteUrl}/wp-json/wc/v3/products/{product_id}/variations`